# Formatting dates - can not find symbol

Tags: java, java-time

Hello everyone I have class that takes input string with date/time value. I have to take that input and convert in different format. Here is example:

```
class Format{
    public String solution(String Dt) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
        String fr = df.format(Dt);
        return fr;
    }
}
```

Input Dt looks like this:

```
March 16, 20018 7:56 AM
```

I'm getting an error from the code above:

```
Format.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
        ^
  symbol:   class DateFormat
```

If anyone knows how to format my input date string please let me know. Thank you.

I have tried this but still throws an error:

```
SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
Date date=localDateFormat.parse(Dt);
```

Error:

```
Format.java:10: error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Date date=localDateFormat.parse(Dt);
```

Comment: You need to import both `java.text.DateFormat` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. Also, the `format` method expects a parameter of type `Date`, it won't compile if you pass it a string.

Comment: @BackSlash Should I use new Date () to convert my input from string to date format? Or some other method?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to reformat your date, you need to parse it first with the `parse` method, then reformat it again with the `format` method.

Comment: @BackSlash I'm just trying to format my date. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Please also note that as of java 8, the "new" way to format dates would be to use the [DateTImeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead, which operates with the new date and time APIs. See [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `DateTimeFormatter`s. First create a formatter to parse in your text:

```
final DateTimeFormatter in = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy K:mm a")
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);
```

`MMMM` is a textual month
`dd` is day of month
`yyyy` is year
`K` is hour of AM/PM (1 or 2 digits)
`mm` is minutes of hour
`a` is AM/PM

The US `Locale` was needed for me because my default `Locale` is UK which parses AM/PM only if they are lowercase. US `Locale` parses them only in uppercase (which they are in your example).

You can then create a formatter to print out your text however you like:

```
final DateTimeFormatter out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
```

Final code:

```
public String solution(String Dt) {
    final DateTimeFormatter in = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy K:mm a")
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);
    final DateTimeFormatter out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    return out.format(in.parse(Dt));
}
```

One flaw in your current output format is that you wont be able to distinguish between AM and PM. You should probably use `HH` (0 - 23) rather than `h` (0 - 12).

Comment: I have input value that is string `Dt` and it's passed in class Format. I need to format data date. This is little confusing why you have to use Locale.US.

Comment: @espresso_coffee you need the correct locale so that the parser interprets the names for the months correctly (among other things).

Comment: That helped, I haven't worked with JAVA in a while so it's different than ColdFusion for example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Sure, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

That's a compilation error, fix missing imports.
The `parse();` `throws` a `ParseException` (checked exception), which is must be explicitely handled:

```
try {
    Date date=localDateFormat.parse(Dt);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); //or log
}
```

Comment: Avoid asking questions in answers. An answer should fully solve the issue. Please include a solution/fix for OP in your answer. (see [answer])

Comment: @espresso_coffee well, you need them... What Editor do you use? Most IDEs will suggest to add them automatically.

Comment: you must import them or use fully qualified class names

Comment: include 'on the classpath'? `DateFormat` is a standard Java class (implicit on classpath), should only need the `import` {valid up to including Java 8, else need the correct module}